# Sequelize error server requires encrypt: true even though I'm setting it

Tags: node.js, azure, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a sequelize call to my azure sql server database. I can connect to the database in SSMS from my machine, however when I try to insert a record through a raw query in sequelize I get the 'Server requires encryption config option set to true' error. I believe I am setting that based on the documentation so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I'm calling this from my local machine and pointing to the cloud azure server. When I make this call from a VM on an azure server I don't see this issue. Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong? Google has failed me thus far.

const sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'password', {
    dialect: 'mssql',
    host: 'server',
    dialectOptions: {
        encrypt: true
      }
  });